# Does it ever make sense for upper layers to have more nodes than lower layers?

Tags: neural-network

Usually people construct neural nets with fewer nodes in the higher layers than the lower layers (excluding the input layer, which could sometimes have fewer columns than the lowest hidden layer).

Are there situations where it makes sense to have a diamond-shaped network, instead of a pyramid shaped network?  I suppose that such a network could be viewed as a basis expansion in the hidden units, much as a network with a few inputs and many hidden layers could be used to model nonlinearities in those hidden units.

Computationally, a diamond-shaped network has many fewer weights as well.  This is because thousands of variables become many many weights when each one feeds into several nodes.

Of course, all information from those thousands of variables needs to pass through a few nodes.  This might not be rich enough for some problems.  But to what degree can this be mitigated by just adding lots and lots of layers?

Alternatively consider the question this way:  given that neural nets with one layer and enough nodes are universal approximators, is it true that a neural net with a small, number of nodes per layers, but many layers, will also be a universal approximator?

Comment: I don't think it ever makes sense to have a diamond shaped network. Imagine starting with `200` inputs, then a hidden layer of `50`, and then a hidden layer of `100`. Your basically 'compressing' the information from `200>50`, then enlaring that same information from `50>100`. And any layer can map a certain function if it's large enough. But it's harder to adapt `100` values from `50` values than `200` values. Don't really have proof though

Comment: Yes. Bottlenecks encourage the network to generalize. Autoencoders are the most typical example.